# Use of "following" as a noun

Tags: nouns

I couldn't find the exact source where I found this. I heard in a video where the speaker says

> We have international following...

(I might have wrongly heard that)

If that is possible to say something like above then my question is:

Is it correct to say:

> He has a great number of international following

Or

> He has a great amount of international following

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I expect it was 'We have *an* international following', where *a following* is a group of supporters or admirers. So you have to say *a large following*, not *a great number/amount of.*